# How to display images in the send grid template

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm passing the product image from my code as a dynamic attribute like below

personalization1.addDynamicTemplateData("image","Base64EncodedURL");

and in my template

Here, the image type can be of any type (png or jpeg).
I referred to the article published in the sendgrid site - https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

But, here the product image will be dynamic in nature. Some times, it is png or jpeg.

So, can you let me know how this can be implemented.

Comment: adding the image tag <img alt="My Image" src="base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANI..moreEncoding"/>